# A quotient ring equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-isomorphism

This is my first time posting on this site so please forgive me if I do something wrong here. I want to try to show that the quotient ring $$\frac{F[x,y,z]}{ \langle xz - (y^2 -1) \rangle}$$ is equal to the intersection of the two polynomial rings $F(x)[y]$ and $F(z)[y]$ where $F$ is some field. In other words, I want to show $$\frac{F[x,y,z]}{ \langle xz - (y^2 -1) \rangle} = F(x)[y] \cap F(z)[y].$$
In $F$. The problem is, I am having a hard time coming up with a reason as to why they are equal in $F$. If anyone could help me, id be greatful.